# Python: loading a text file containing an array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load a text file in python using NumPy library. The text file has float type data on 9516 rows & 39 columns & is 6.2mbites. The following command is used:

```
p=np.loadtxt(fname = "E:\PhD Data\Aphrodite data\APHRO\outfile\rain2007.txt")
```

& got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-126-dfa85ca1950b>", line 1, in <module>
    p=np.loadtxt(fname = "E:\PhD Data\Aphrodite data\APHRO\outfile\rain2007.txt")

  File "C:\Users\Sohaib\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 962, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)

  File "C:\Users\Sohaib\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 266, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)

  File "C:\Users\Sohaib\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 624, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)

ain2007.txt not found.phrodite data\APHRO\outfile
```

The same command is working with a smaller size file (26 rows & 39 columns). Can you tell me the possible reasons behind this error?

Comment: You need to either put an `r` in front of the string (use a [raw string/string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)) or double up your backslashes in the path.

Comment: Can you add how you load the text (`np.loadtxt`), with the path you're using, when it's working?

Comment: It's having trouble finding the file.  The load hasn't even started.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`p=np.loadtxt(fname = "E:/PhD Data/Aphrodite data/APHRO/outfile/rain2007.txt")`

the `\` is a special character in Python.